# Conflict-free schdule?

Tags: algorithm, graph, scheduler

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a graph (as in graph theory) to find a few conflict-free schedules for almost anything. For example:

You have 4 courses you need to take and you want to know what section you should sign up for. Your input should be the course subjects and course number (e.g. MATH 100, MATH 101, MATH 200, etc.) and the output should be the sections you should take to avoid a time-conflict with any other class.

What graph theory algorithm should I use for this? How would I use it?

Comment: This is broad. I don't see any formal objective. Start with [(maximum-weight) independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#:~:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20an%20independent,.) Remark: your graph *probably* will be special (interval-graph, chordal, perfect) rendering the NP-hard problem poly-time solvable.

Comment: I'd suggest you read Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual, it will give you an idea how to start designing algos for problems. From your vague description, it's hard to give directions though.